# Django Moving Models

Tags: python, django, database, model, refactoring

I have a django application I'm trying to refactor. There's a million and five ways it seems to migrate models from an existing django app to a new one however I wanted to run by what seems like the easiest solution.

Let's say my current application is called 'main-app' in said application i have a model 'user'. This would create a table called 'main-app_user' or something similar.

Let's say I want to move the user model to a new app 'core', some tutorials state this is as easy as pointing the new model to the old table like so

```
class User(models.Model):
     ...
     class Meta:
          db_table = 'main-app_user'
```

I was curious if there was any catch to this I suppose? Many tutorial make this *way* more complicated so I'm curious why this isn't just the de-facto solution or if there are any drawbacks to this vs others. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please read this - https://realpython.com/move-django-model/

Comment: @Ram that was actually where I got this idea - they don't really discuss what the drawbacks are of this method vs the more involved migrations if you have any insight

Comment: Hey, did you find any simple solution? I'm trying to do the same and we already have couple of production servers, so doing the multistep solution would be a a huge problem. Is there a way so that Django will detect that it's the same model and won't create any DELETE/CREATE migrations